# Random Forest Classification Model

Tags: r, model, classification, random-forest

I am trying to code in R-programming and I keep getting an error. I can't figure out for the life of me, what's wrong.

This is the error I keep receiving:

[1] "Confusion Matrix: TRAINING set based on random forest model built using 5 trees"
Error in table(train.data$size, train.data.predict): all arguments must have the same length
Traceback:

1. table(train.data$size, train.data.predict)
2. stop("all arguments must have the same length")